# Matplotlib.mlab Objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, signals, matplotlib.mlab

My code:

```
(x, y, t) = mlab.psd(
    d,
    Fs=1.0 / h['xdelta'],
    NFFT=512)
psd = 20 * np.log10(y)
plt.plot(x, y, t)
plt.show()
```

I just get a the following error upon execution:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.
```

I feel like this is something simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.
How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: toy data for d, h would let others run the code

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. When reporting about an error also include the full error traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this error mean: ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950074/what-does-this-error-mean-valueerror-shape-mismatch-objects-cannot-be-broadca)