# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do some data validation with numpy and I don't really understand this error. see code below:

```
conditions = [
    (np.where(df['DD'].eq('No DD Required'))),
    (np.where(df['DD'].eq('DD Required'))) & (np.where(df['On Direct Debit'].eq('No'))),
    (np.where(df['DD'].eq('DD Required'))) & (np.where(df['On Direct Debit'].eq('Yes')))
    ]


values = ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass']

df['DDValidation'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `&` [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) is not the one you wanted. `&` in python is a *bitwise* AND, not the *logical*  AND, which is `and`.

Change your code to something like

```py
conditions = [
    (np.where(df['DD'].eq('No DD Required'))),
    (np.where(df['DD'].eq('DD Required'))) and (np.where(df['On Direct Debit'].eq('No'))),
    (np.where(df['DD'].eq('DD Required'))) and (np.where(df['On Direct Debit'].eq('Yes')))
    ]
```

for more info, a [discussion of the distinction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051349/what-is-the-difference-between-bitwise-and-and-logical-and) between these different ANDs

Comment: I did try that and got an error I understand even less:  ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Well, what are the shapes of the two sides of the logical `and`?

Comment: @Jkendrick this is a separate issue that was being masked by the error causing the question you asked. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950074/valueerror-shape-mismatch-objects-cannot-be-broadcast-to-a-single-shape for a discussion of your new error.

Comment: Ben, your link in for C#, not python and numpy.  In Python, `and/or` are short-circuiting operators.  In `A and B`, if `A` is 'truthy' then it returns `A`.  `np.where(...)` always returns a tuple of 1d arrays.  `and` does not help in "combining" the results of the 2 `wheres`.

Comment: While for base Python numbers, `&` is bitwise, for numpy arrays it is element-wise, the `np.logical_and` `ufunc`.  However the OP is trying to "combine" tuples produced by `np.nonzero`.

Answer (score 0):

This has more of a chance of working.  You haven't provided a sample `df`, so I can't test it.

```
conditions = [
    df['DD'].eq('No DD Required',
    (df['DD'].eq('DD Required')) & (df['On Direct Debit'].eq('No')),
    (df['DD'].eq('DD Required')) & (df['On Direct Debit'].eq('Yes'))
    ]
```

Look at what `np.select` expects as its first argument:

```
condlist : list of bool ndarrays
```

Each of those lines needs to a bool numpy array.

When developing, and debugging, code, test each step.  Don't guess or assume.  Look at what `np.where(...)` produces.  Does that look at all like a bool array?  And read the docs - for `np.where` and `np.select` for a start.